# Why is starting a thread blocked by another thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, events, awt

I encountered a strange problem while writing a prototype for an architecture.

I tried to create two threads that dispatch the same commands independently. The first thread was to use a `Scanner` and the second one to rely on Swing. The problem was that the first thread prevented the second thread from starting. The second thread started only after the scanner was given enough input. Forcing the first thread sleep until the second thread started also fixed the problem temporarily.

The following example reproduces this behavior quite consistently. Sleeping between the calls makes it even more consistent.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public final class Bug {
    public static void main(final String[] arguments) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("The commands are \"wait\" and \"quit\".");
                final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                loop: while (true) {
                    System.out.print("Enter a command: ");
                    final String command = scanner.nextLine();
                    switch (command.toLowerCase()) {
                    case "exit":
                    case "quit":
                        break loop;
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Use \"wait\" or \"quit\" instead of \"" + command + "\".");
                    case "wait":
                    }
                }
                scanner.close();
            }
        }).start();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);//improves consistency
        }
        catch (final InterruptedException exception) {}

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final JFrame frame = new JFrame("Commands");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setResizable(false);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new JButton("Wait"), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
                final JButton button = new JButton("Quit");
                button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent event) {
                        frame.dispose();
                    }
                });
                frame.add(button, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the second thread start properly? Am I to blame?

A [similar problem](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4206767) was submitted as a bug over ten years ago.

---

Running `java -version` results in

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

and `cmd -info` in

```
Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.
```

if that matters.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code posted above that would explain the behavior you're describing. This is a puzzle to me.

Comment: Works for me: Ubuntu 13.04; openjdk 1.7.0_21

Comment: I tried this code on Windows 7, jdk 1.7. It works. The problem in your case is something else.

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me, although I had to replace the switch by a series of if/else if (I'm using Java 1.6)

```
final String command = scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
if (command.equals("exit") || command.equals("quit")) {
    break loop;
} else if (!command.equals("wait")) {
    System.out.println("Use \"wait\" or \"quit\" instead of \"" + command + "\".");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you're using EventQueue.invokeLater() for the second thread.  By the time that thread starts, the first thread could already be waiting for user input at the console.  I could imagine that the EventQueue might not fire your second thread immediately because the first thread is already waiting for input, and thus clogging the event pump.

I would suggest you use a different mechanism to start the second thread.  Why not start it just like your first thread?

Also, I agree with other comments that this code should be refactored to help make it more clear what's going on and why.